Can you change the text color in a chart for an individual data label (but not the entire series) in the Google Sheets API?
So I'm trying to use the Google Sheets API for chart editing in R (using the googlesheets4 package's request_generate() and request_make() functions). I want to change the color of individual data labels in a bar chart (so the BasicChartSpec object), but not for an entire series.
Within the BasicChartSeries structure, you can add a DataLabel object and it accepts a TextFormat argument, but it looks like it only accepts one argument for all data labels in the series.
I saw the styleOverrides argument that accepts a BasicSeriesDataPointStyleOverride object containing "index" (so you can specify which exact data point within the series) and "color" arguments. However, when I tried it, it changed the color for the bar / point itself, not the label.
I tried making these changes to a chart manually with the Google Sheets GUI (see image) and then using the gs4_get() function (which uses the get API method) with fields = "sheets(charts)" specified to see how R interpreted the chart through the Google Sheets API. What I saw is that the differing data label colors do show up in the styleOverrides lists, but the only argument within it specified is the index. The R output for the "Category 1" series is below.
$basicChart$series
$basicChart$series[[1]]
$basicChart$series[[1]]$series
$basicChart$series[[1]]$series$sourceRange
$basicChart$series[[1]]$series$sourceRange$sources
$basicChart$series[[1]]$series$sourceRange$sources[[1]]
$basicChart$series[[1]]$series$sourceRange$sources[[1]]$sheetId
[1] 44021641

$basicChart$series[[1]]$series$sourceRange$sources[[1]]$startRowIndex
[1] 0

$basicChart$series[[1]]$series$sourceRange$sources[[1]]$endRowIndex
[1] 5

$basicChart$series[[1]]$series$sourceRange$sources[[1]]$startColumnIndex
[1] 2

$basicChart$series[[1]]$series$sourceRange$sources[[1]]$endColumnIndex
[1] 3





$basicChart$series[[1]]$targetAxis
[1] "LEFT_AXIS"

$basicChart$series[[1]]$dataLabel
$basicChart$series[[1]]$dataLabel$type
[1] "CUSTOM"

$basicChart$series[[1]]$dataLabel$textFormat
$basicChart$series[[1]]$dataLabel$textFormat$foregroundColor
named list()

$basicChart$series[[1]]$dataLabel$textFormat$fontFamily
[1] "sans-serif"

$basicChart$series[[1]]$dataLabel$textFormat$fontSize
[1] 12

$basicChart$series[[1]]$dataLabel$textFormat$foregroundColorStyle
$basicChart$series[[1]]$dataLabel$textFormat$foregroundColorStyle$rgbColor
named list()



$basicChart$series[[1]]$dataLabel$placement
[1] "OUTSIDE_END"

$basicChart$series[[1]]$dataLabel$customLabelData
$basicChart$series[[1]]$dataLabel$customLabelData$sourceRange
$basicChart$series[[1]]$dataLabel$customLabelData$sourceRange$sources
$basicChart$series[[1]]$dataLabel$customLabelData$sourceRange$sources[[1]]
$basicChart$series[[1]]$dataLabel$customLabelData$sourceRange$sources[[1]]$sheetId
[1] 44021641

$basicChart$series[[1]]$dataLabel$customLabelData$sourceRange$sources[[1]]$startRowIndex
[1] 0

$basicChart$series[[1]]$dataLabel$customLabelData$sourceRange$sources[[1]]$endRowIndex
[1] 5

$basicChart$series[[1]]$dataLabel$customLabelData$sourceRange$sources[[1]]$startColumnIndex
[1] 3

$basicChart$series[[1]]$dataLabel$customLabelData$sourceRange$sources[[1]]$endColumnIndex
[1] 4






$basicChart$series[[1]]$color
$basicChart$series[[1]]$color$green
[1] 0.3215686

$basicChart$series[[1]]$color$blue
[1] 1


**$basicChart$series[[1]]$styleOverrides
$basicChart$series[[1]]$styleOverrides[[1]]
named list()

$basicChart$series[[1]]$styleOverrides[[2]]
$basicChart$series[[1]]$styleOverrides[[2]]$index
[1] 1


$basicChart$series[[1]]$styleOverrides[[3]]
$basicChart$series[[1]]$styleOverrides[[3]]$index
[1] 2


$basicChart$series[[1]]$styleOverrides[[4]]
$basicChart$series[[1]]$styleOverrides[[4]]$index
[1] 3
**


$basicChart$series[[1]]$colorStyle
$basicChart$series[[1]]$colorStyle$rgbColor
$basicChart$series[[1]]$colorStyle$rgbColor$green
[1] 0.3215686

$basicChart$series[[1]]$colorStyle$rgbColor$blue
[1] 1


Does this mean that the Google Sheets API doesn't support this? Or is there something I'm missing? Has anyone else had success doing this with the Google Sheets API?
